# Moving asteriods randomly with opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glew

I'm trying to move asteriods in a random manner. I pass in a vector of asteriods as paramenter, clearing the screen at the start of of the method to prevent be multiple drawing of the asteriods drawn on the screen just like this:

[image]

However, with the codes that I coded, all the asteriods are moving in the same direction. I need to make it a random movement, please help. 
Below are my codes:

```
void Entity::move(GLFWwindow * window, vector<Entity> allAsteriods, Entity &sp ) {

    DrawEntity de = DrawEntity();

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);   

        for (int i = 0; i < allAsteriods.size(); i++) {

            glLoadIdentity();
            glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

            float x = allAsteriods[i].return_PositionVector().back().get_X();
            float y = allAsteriods[i].return_PositionVector().back().get_Y();

            glPushMatrix();
            glTranslatef(x, y, 0.0); // 3. Translate to the object's position.

            de.drawEntity(allAsteriods[i]);

            float additionalX = GenerateRandom(0.10, 0.90);
            float additionalY   = GenerateRandom(0.10, 0.90);

            allAsteriods[i].addTo_PositionVector(x + additionalX, y + additionalY);       
            glPopMatrix();      
        }
        de.drawEntity(sp);

        // Swap front and back buffers
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        // Poll for and process events
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
}
```

Comment: you have to check the PositionVector you generate. They seem to be initialized with the same value.

Comment: What does `GenerateRandom` do?

Comment: yeah, the positionVector is initalized with the same value ><

Comment: GenerateRandom generate a random number within to 0.10 - 0.90.

Answer (score 2):

You are adding a random position to your asteroids every frame (you can see how they jiggle around as they move down the screen). Your random positions are only from 0.1 to 0.9 in both X and Y, so they will only be moving towards the lower left of the screen.

To fix this, you need to do the following:

- Inside your Entity class you need to store a `Velocity` vector separate from the position.
- When you first initalise your asteroid Entities, you need to randomly assign them each a velocity, BUT you need to choose a velocity from *-1 to 1 for both X and Y*:

```
allAsteroids[i].velocity.x = GenerateRandom(-1.0, 1.0)
allAsteroids[i].velocity.y = GenerateRandom(-1.0, 1.0)
```

- Inside your main game loop, you must add the velocity to the position every frame:

```
//Not sure why you're doing it like this - it should be easy to get X and Y from vectors, but I'll do it the same way:

float velX = allAsteriods[i].return_VelocityVector().back().get_X();
float velY = allAsteriods[i].return_VelocityVector().back().get_Y();

allAsteriods[i].addTo_PositionVector(x + velX, y + velY);
```

Also, your

```
 glLoadIdentity();
 glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
```

Should not be inside the looping through all the asteroids. This should be done only once per frame at the top of your game loop. Your per-asteroid loop should start with a `glPushMatrix()` and end with a `glPopMatrix()`

Comment: Thank you, I changed the codes accordingly and the asteroids do move randomly however, there is only one asteroid being drawn on the screen even though there are 3 items in the allAsteriod Vector.
It's highly because I still have glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); before looping allAsteriods. Without the glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT) portion, there are one chunk of asteroids drawn to the screen at the position it is moving instead of one asteroid moving across the screen just like the screenshot I posted with this post. Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: @LimTing That could be a lot of different reasons. 1) Your positions are all being initialised to the same X,Y coordinates. 2) Your init function has assigned the same velocity for all 3 asteroids. 

It's difficult to tell without looking at the whole code.

Comment: ahh... I've been trying to move the object without glClear method but I haven't been successful...

Comment: The codes used to initialize allAsteriod vector is  


`vector<Entity> Entity::initAsteriodVector()
{
 Entity e = Entity();

 vector<Entity> allEntity = vector<Entity>();

 vector<Vector2D> pos1{ Vector2D(500, 250) };
 Entity a = Entity(pos1, pos1, 0, "asteriod");
 allEntity.push_back(a);

 vector<Vector2D> pos2{ Vector2D(360, 400) };
 Entity a2 = Entity(pos2, pos2, 0, "asteriod");
 allEntity.push_back(a2);


 vector<Vector2D> pos3{ Vector2D(60, 50) };
 Entity a3 = Entity(pos3, pos3, 0, "asteriod");
 allEntity.push_back(a3);

 return allEntity;
}`

Comment: Codes in the draw method are:

`void DrawGame::draw(GLFWwindow* window, vector<Entity> drawAllEntity) {

 DrawEntity de = DrawEntity();

 vector<Vector2D> pos = vector<Vector2D>();
 pos.push_back(Vector2D(820, 460));

 Entity e = Entity(pos, pos, 0, "spaceship");

 de.drawEntity(e);

 for (int i = 0; i < drawAllEntity.size(); i++) {

  float Velocity_x = e.GenerateRandom(-1.0, 1.0);
  float Velocity_y = e.GenerateRandom(-1.0, 1.0);
  drawAllEntity[i].addTo_velocityVector(Velocity_x, Velocity_y);
  drawAllEntity[i].move(window, drawAllEntity, e);
 }
}`

Comment: I changed the drawAllEntity[i].move for loop to :

`for (int i = 0; i < allAsteriods.size(); i++) {

 glPushMatrix();

 float x = allAsteriods[i].return_PositionVector().back().get_X();
 float y = allAsteriods[i].return_PositionVector().back().get_Y();
     float velX = allAsteriods[i].return_velocityVector().back().get_X();
     float velY = allAsteriods[i].return_velocityVector().back().get_Y();

 glTranslatef(x, y, 0.0); // 3. Translate to the object's position.
 allAsteriods[i].addTo_PositionVector(x + velX, y + velY);
 de.drawEntity(allAsteriods[i]);
 
glPopMatrix();
  }`

Comment: @LimTing Change your position vector instead of `(820, 460)` for each asteroid, make it `GenerateRandom(0,800), GenerateRandom(0,600)`.


Also, I see you have a `GenerateRandom` function inside the `Entity` class. You should only have 1 random number generator and make **sure** that it does in fact give you completely random numbers each time and you are not initialising them with the same random seed.